# How to install python commandline script with setuptools in conda environment on windows?

Tags: windows, conda, setuptools

How to install python commandline script with setuptools on windows? I have the following code in `setup.py`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    ...
    'scripts': ['scripts/Mint'],
    ...
}

setup(**config)
```

I activate the conda environment `conda activate mint` and run `python setup.py install`. Under Linux the scrip `Mint` ends up under `.../miniconda3/envs/mint/bin` and it is ready to use. Under Windows there is no bin folder at all and the script is not found.

Comment: Under w32 the directory is named `Scripts`.

Comment: I found the script under `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mint\Scripts`, but windows doesn't know what to do with it. And it is also not the script itself, buta file that is supposed to call the script.

Comment: `conda activate mint` should prepend it to your `PATH`.

Comment: Not under windows apparently.

Comment: For me it actually works under windows. The setup.py uses setuptools and has the entry "entry_points = {
            'console_scripts': ['aedat4to2=aedat4to2.aedat4to2:main']
      }" and when I activate the env setuptools has installed aedat4to2.exe in "C:\Users\tobid\anaconda3\envs\aedat4to2" so that a powershell finds the .exe... Seems OK.